# How to create scheduled task with method that requires parameters

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a scheduled task that will give all information about a player. The fact is that the method responsible for collecting information about the player requires parameters, while `@Sheduled` does not allow you to enter parameters.

[image]

```
  private void playerInfo(PlayerService playerService) {

        Player player = playerService.getPlayer();
        log.info("Player {}: gold {} | wood {} | food {}", player.getId(), player.getGold(), player.getFood(), player.getWood());
    }
    

    @Scheduled
            (cron = "0 0/10 * * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(playerInfo());

    }
}
```

And the expected error in this case:

```
 found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerService` could be injected in the constructor instead of injecting it in the method.

```
private final PlayerService playerService;

public GameInfoService(PlayerService playerService){
    this.playerService = playerService;
}
```

Now: `private void playerInfo(PlayerService playerService)`
becomes `private void playerInfo()`